# Аномалии в кастомном классе строки

Tags: c++, строки

Так вот, я начал писать класс для реализации строки `C++`, хотя использую я методики из `C`, впрочем сейчас это неважно. Как и обычный класс `string` из `STL` основная задача данной приблуды - динамическое выделение памяти под строку.

Я начал писать это чудо, но уже на стадии реализации конструктора класса наткнулся на некую аномалию, она возникает не всегда, но это не меняет ситуацию. Иногда когда я преобразую мой блок для хранения данных в `const char*` с помощью стандартного `type-cast` я получаю некую аномалию в конце строки. Стоит подметить что я заметил её когда выводил данные с помощью `<iostream>` библиотеки.

Мой блок для хранения данных типа `uint8_t*` или `unsigned char*`. Впрочем мне понятно как решить данную проблему, нужно просто записать символ окончания строки `\0` на конечный адрес блока. Но всё же мне интересно, это обязательно делать, или я что-то сделал не так и теперь из-за этого страдаю?

```
class string {
private:
    uint8_t* m_data = 0;
    size_t m_length = 0;

public:
    string();
    string(char _var);
    string(char* _var);
    string(const char* _var);
    string(const string& _var);

    const char* to_str() const;
    size_t length() const;

    ~string();
};

string::string() {
    m_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(0);
}

string::string(char _var) {
    m_length++;
    m_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(m_length);
    memcpy_s(m_data, m_length, (void*)_var, m_length);
}

string::string(char *_var) {
    m_length = strlen(_var);
    m_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(m_length);
    memcpy_s(m_data, m_length, (uint8_t*)_var, m_length);
}

string::string(const char* _var) {
    m_length = strlen(_var);
    m_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(m_length);
    memcpy_s(m_data, m_length, (uint8_t*)_var, m_length);
}

string::string(const string& _var) {
    m_length = _var.length();
    m_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(m_length);
    memcpy_s(m_data, m_length, (uint8_t*)_var.to_str(), m_length);
}

const char* string::to_str() const {
    return (const char*)m_data;
}

size_t string::length() const {
    return m_length;
}

string::~string() {
    free(m_data);
}
```

Данных на этот счёт в интернете я на удивление не нашёл, хотя возможно я просто не правильно задал вопрос.

Comment: Строки всегда должны заканчиваться нуль-символом `'\0'` [Нуль-терминированная строка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0). А зачем хранить m_data как uint8_t*, а не как char*?

Comment: Строки в понимании стандартной библиотеки си должны заканчиваться \0. Если вы пишете свою обработку строк и храните размер отдельно, то нуль-терминал совсем необязателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом конструкторе `string(char)` вы выделяете память под ровно один символ (кстати `m_length++` плохая идея, лучше `m_length = 1`).

Во втором конструкторе `string(char*)` вы измеряете размер строки при помощи функции `strlen`, которая принимает «строку в стиле Си» и возвращает размер с учетом терминального нуля. ASCII строка из одного символа всегда будет иметь размер 2.

```
string('a').length() == 1;
string("a").length() == 2;
```

Но эти все конструкторы создают нормальную (в широком понимании) копию строки во всех случаях. Ошибка находится в функции `to_str()`, которая возвращает указатель на константный char, что стандартной библиотекой воспринимается как строка в стиле Си и, соответственно, должна иметь терминальный ноль. Что имеет смысл, ведь указатель на память не несёт информации о том, сколько этой памяти доступно.

Здесь нужно сделать выбор: либо хранить всегда терминальный ноль в строке, либо всегда его убирать.
Если его не хранить, то единственная выгода - экономия одного байта. А при конвертировании в строку в стиле Си придётся выделять память, дописывать ноль, а потом ещё и удалять её.
А если хранить, то нужно лишь в нескольких местах обработать этот случай.

Есть ещё третий вариант – убрать из интерфейса конвертацию в строку в стиле Си, что сильно сузит область применения этой библиотеки.

Comment: @xm1r10n когда выделяешь память нужно добавить один байт для нулевого символа если в исходной строке его нет. А потом его туда нужно не забыть записать.